# Fedora Linux - Ethernet interface spontaneously dropping out with "Card not present on Slot" error

Tags: linux, fedora, ethernet

I am running Fedora 17 Linux on an Advantech ARK-3440 computer ([datasheet](http://downloadt.advantech.com/ProductFile/PIS/ARK-3440%20A2/Product%20-%20Datasheet/ARK-3440%20A2_DS(09.09.15)20150909145406.pdf)).

From time to time (say 5 times since Jan 1), it spontaneously loses its network interface.  From the Linux /var/log/messages* logs, I see that the interface appears to briefly go away and then come back.  But, upon coming back, it cannot be added by Linux again.

Here is an excerpt:

```
Jan 28 16:17:27 localhost kernel: [168424.859993] pciehp 0000:00:1c.4:pcie04: Card not present on Slot(0-4)
Jan 28 16:17:27 localhost kernel: [168424.864098] pciehp 0000:00:1c.4:pcie04: Card present on Slot(0-4)
Jan 28 16:17:27 localhost avahi-daemon[423]: Interface p2p1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan 28 16:17:27 localhost avahi-daemon[423]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface p2p1.IPv4 with address 10.9.20.224.
Jan 28 16:17:27 localhost avahi-daemon[423]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::20b:abff:feb5:9532 on p2p1.
Jan 28 16:17:27 localhost avahi-daemon[423]: Withdrawing address record for 10.9.20.224 on p2p1.
Jan 28 16:17:27 localhost avahi-daemon[423]: Withdrawing workstation service for p2p1.
Jan 28 16:17:28 localhost kernel: [168425.886823] pciehp 0000:00:1c.4:pcie04: Device 0000:05:00.0 already exists at 0000:05:00, cannot hot-add
Jan 28 16:17:28 localhost kernel: [168425.886833] pciehp 0000:00:1c.4:pcie04: Cannot add device at 0000:05:00
```

Here is the uname and lspci output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.3.4-5.fc17.i686.PAE #1 SMP Mon May 7 17:37:39 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 06)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev 06)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82583V Gigabit Network Connection
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

Does anyone have experience with this problem, or any suggestions on what this might be or how to troubleshoot?  Could this be a true hardware problem?  Or more likely a problem in Linux?

I have searched and found similar posts on the "Card not present" topic but no suitable answers.  Some suggest rebuilding the Linux without hotplug support...

Any assistance is much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Fedora 17 is years after EOL and not supported. Please update to something more recent if you expect some reasonable answers.

Comment: In addition to what Jakuje says, newer Fedora will have a newer kernel, with newer drivers, so it's _definitely_ the first thing to try anyway.